# Any Java library for address extraction from emails?

Tags: java, parsing, open-source, street-address, information-extraction

I'm looking for an Java open-source library which is able to extract address information from a (German) email (signature). The library should find

- name
- street
- city, city code/postal code
- email
- tel/fax

address-parser.com is an commercial product, but a free (albeit simple) library would be great.

stackoverflow.com/questions/16413/parse-usable-street-address-city-state-zip-from-a-string is asking for something similar, but my problem is broader because the address information is hidden in a complete email. And there isn't a solution either...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

well you just use [javamail](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/) to get the parts that compose the email until you find the one containing the signature (there might be more than one, for example one text/plain and another text/html inside a multipart/alternative, but the address will be the same in both), and then apply the solution given in the question you mention

Comment: I know how to do that. I am looking for a library my friend.